# how to read python flask jsonify response object

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a `python` function which returns `Flask jsonify` object. When I try to read this returned `json` object using `get_json()` or even `json()` it throws error. Here is my code:

```
from flask import jsonify

def funct1(par1):
    if par1 == 'Hi':
       return jsonify(result=1,msg='Hello')
    else:
       return jsonify(result=0,msg='Sorry')

def func2():
    response = funct1('Hi')
    rsp_js = response.get_json() # This throws error
    print(rsp_js)
```

When I execute above I get error as `Response object has no attribute get_json`. I tried `json()` as well but get the same error. How can I read the returned jsonify object?

**NOTE**: I have flask version 0.12.2

Comment: which version of flask are you using? `get_json` is only a method on response objects in flask 1.0 and above, it is not available in 0.12

Comment: @MatthewStory I have flask version 0.12.2. What is the syntax for that version?

Comment: See my answer for more here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`get_json` was not added to response objects in flask until [version 1.0](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Response.get_json). In previous versions, you need to use `get_data`:

```
import json
json.loads(response.get_data().decode("utf-8"))
```

Having said this, I would caution you against calling route methods directly from other functions (except for testing), or returning response objects from non-route methods.

If you are attempting to test this method, you should consider using the [`test_client`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#the-testing-skeleton):

```
with app.test_client() as client:
    json.loads(client.get("the/url").get_data().decode("utf-8"))
    # ...
```